# Combine multiple QMainWindow into one as tabs in QTabWidget

Tags: python, c++, qt, qt-designer

So, my project had been divided into multiple portions each working independently. Me and my group members worked on individual portions and now I want to combine all of them into a single `QMainWindow`. Currently I have menu items in each `QMainWindow` that makes jumping from one part to another possible.. (by closing the current window and launching another within the same `QApplication`)

But I want to do it more elegantly, using `QTabWidget`, so that each part would have its own tab. How do I achieve this?
(Btw, i'm using QT Designer for designing the UI)

What I've done: 
-make a new window, add a `QTabWidget`, drag and drop all widgets from previous `QMainWindow` into separate tabs.

This works perfectly from design perspective. 
However I don't know how to combine their code. They are in separate classes inherited from `QMainWindow`.

Is there no way but to manually add all the associated slots and functions into the new mainWindow?

Answer (score 0):

As each portion is a QMainWindow, each QMainWindow could be put in a tabWidget.

Suppose Portion_one_QMainWindow derives from QMainWindow.
I use a working code, similar to the following one :

```
QTabWidget *tabMaster = new QTabWidget;   
Portion_one_QMainWindow *Portion_one = new Portion_one_MainWindow;
tabMaster.addTab(Portion_one, QIcon("images/portion_one.png"), "name_of_portion_one" );
```

The big effort is to retrieve the code from the portions into a common place in order to build your "master launcher".